# Webview plugins are no longer supported. Is there another way to display flash?

Tags: android, html, flash, webview, google-swiffy

I am making my flash game into an Android app with the following code. It works just fine but the compiler gives the error

> The method setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState) from the type
>   WebSettings is deprecated

Here is the code.

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);

webview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/myflashgame.swf");
```

This code works but it wont for long.

Is there another way to make an app of my flash game? I tried converting the .swf file to html5 with Google Swiffy but the game became very slow and laggy. Is there another way?